Non-linear recursion relation with fractional exponent
I'm trying to solve the following non-linear recursion relation:
$a_{n+1} = a_n + c\cdot a_n^b, \quad n \geq 1$,
where $a_1 > 0$, and $c > 0$ and $0 < b < 1$ are constants. Mostly I'd like to know the asymptotic behavior of $a_n$
for large $n$, and ideally a lower bound for $a_n$. I suspect both should be approximately given
by the solution to the corresponding ODE,
$f'(x) = f(x)^b, \quad f(1) = a_1$,
which is solved by $f(x) = \left[a_1^{1-b} + c\cdot (1-b) \cdot (x-1)\right]^{\frac{1}{1-b}}$. This suggests that $a_n$ for large $n$ should be approximately given by $f(n)$.
It is not so hard to show that $a_n \leq f(n)$ for $n \geq 1$, but since I need a lower bound this is not directly helpful. Since the recursion relation is so simple I hope that there might be a clever technique for solving it exactly, maybe by a change of variables, or that recursion relations like this have been investigated before; however, I wasn't able to find much except for some special cases (e.g. $b = \frac{1}{2}$).
Does anyone here have any ideas, or a useful reference?

@IosifPinelis it is, thanks for catching that. I've added it to the question.

Using the rescaling substitution $a_n=c^{1/(1-b)}x_n$, rewrite the recursion a bit more simply, as
$$x_{n+1}=x_n+x_n^b$$
for $n\ge1$, with some real $x_1>0$ (so as to eliminate the inessential parameter $c$). You showed that
$$x_n\le f_n:=(x_1^{1-b}+(1-b)(n-1))^{1/(1-b)}
=(s+(1-b)n)^{1/(1-b)}$$
for $n\ge1$, where $s:=x_1^{1-b}+b-1>b-1$.
So, for $n\ge1$,
$$x_{n+1}=x_n(1+x_n^{b-1})\ge x_n(1+f_n^{b-1})
=x_n\Big(1+\frac1{s+(1-b)n}\Big).$$
So, for $n\ge1$, by (say) induction on $n$,
$$x_n\ge g_n:=x_1 \prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\Big(1+\frac1{s+(1-b)k}\Big) \\
=G_{b,s}\,\frac{\Gamma \left(n+\frac{1+s}{1-b}\right)}
{\Gamma \left(n+\frac{s}{1-b}\right) }
\sim G_{b,s}\,n^{\frac{1}{1-b}}
$$
as $n\to\infty$, where
$$G_{b,s}:=\frac{\Gamma \left(1+\frac{s}{1-b}\right)}
{\Gamma\left(1+\frac{1+s}{1-b}\right) }\,x_1
=\frac{\Gamma \left(1+\frac{s}{1-b}\right)}
{\Gamma\left(1+\frac{1+s}{1-b}\right) }\,(1-b+s)^{\frac{1}{1-b}}.$$
This can be compared with
$$x_n\le f_n\sim F_b\, n^{1/(1-b)},$$
where
$$F_b:=(1-b)^{1/(1-b)}.$$
So, up to a constant factor, $x_n$ behaves as $n^{1/(1-b)}$ for large $n$. This apparently is the best that can be done here in simple and explicit form, because it is hardly possible to accurately account for what happens at the initial few steps of the recursion.
Actually, the ratio
$$R_{b,s}:=\frac{G_{b,s}}{F_b},$$
of the constant factors $G_{b,s}$ and $F_b$ in the asymptotic lower and upper bounds on $x_n$ goes to $1$ for each $b\in(0,1)$ as $s\to\infty$ (that is, as $x_1\to\infty$). Indeed, it is intuitively clear that, if the initial value $x_1$ is large, then initial few steps of the recursion matter little.
Moreover, the following graph $\{(b,s,R_{b,s})\colon 0<b<1,b-1<s<5\}$ suggests that $R_{b,s}$ is rather close to $1$ already if $s>0$ is not small while $b$ is not close to $1$.


Brilliant, thank you! Nice to see that the upper and lower bounds converge so quickly in practice, too.

@JessevanRhijn : Thank you for your appreciation. Your question was well prepared, and I relied on work that you had done.

Below is a different approach to obtain an asymptotic lower bound for $a_n$. Like Iosif found, it yields a lower bound that is a constant factor away from the upper bound $f(n)$.
Since the initial value is positive, there exists some $n_0$ such that $a_{n_0} \geq (1-b)^{\frac{1}{1-b}} c^{\frac{1}{1-b}}$.
As we are only interested in the large-$n$ behavior of the solution, we can shift the index by $n_0$ and instead analyze
$$
y_{n+1} = y_{n} + c \cdot y_n^b, \quad y_1 = (1-b)^{\frac{1}{1-b}}c^{\frac{1}{1-b}}.
$$
Let $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function satisfying
$f(1) = y_1$ and
$$
f'(x) = c' \cdot f(x)^b,
$$
for some constant $c' < c$ to be determined later. First, observe that this differential equation is uniquely solved by
$$
f(x) = \left[
y_1^{1-b} + c'(1-b)(x-1)
\right]^{\frac{1}{1-b}}.
$$
For $x \geq 1$, we first write $f(x+1) = f(x) + \int_{x}^{x+1} f'(s)\mathrm{d} s$ and use the differential equation above to find
\begin{align*}
f(x+1) &= f(x) + c'\int_{x}^{x+1} f(s)^b \mathrm{d} x  \\
&= f(x) + c'\int_{x}^{x+1} f(s-1)^b \left(\frac{f(s)}{f(s-1)}\right)^b \mathrm{d} x
\\
&\leq f(x) + c'\cdot \max_{s \in [x, x+1]}
\left(\frac{f(s)}{f(s-1)}\right)^b \int_{x}^{x+1} f(s-1)^b \mathrm{d} x \\
&\leq f(x) + c'\cdot 
\max_{x \geq 1} \max_{s \in [x, x+1]} \left(\frac{f(s)}{f(s-1)}\right)^b 
f(x)^b,
\end{align*}
since $f$ is monotone increasing. Here, we use the fact that $f(s)$ is positive for
$s \geq 0$.
We can compute the maximum above exactly:
\begin{align*}
\max_{x \geq 1} \max_{s \in [x, x+1]} \left(\frac{f(s)}{f(s-1)}\right)^b 
&= \max_{x\geq 1}\max_{s \in [x, x+1]} \left(
\frac{y_1^{1-b} + c'(1-b)(s-1)}
{y_1^{1-b} + c'(1-b)(s-2)}
\right)^{\frac{b}{1-b}} \\
&= \max_{x \geq 1} \left(
\frac{y_1^{1-b} + c'(1-b)(x-1)}
{y_1^{1-b} + c'(1-b)(x-2)}
\right)^{\frac{b}{1-b}} \\
&=
\left(
\frac{y_1^{1-b}}
{y_1^{1-b} - c'(1-b)}
\right)^{\frac{b}{1-b}}  \\
&= \left(\frac{c}{c - c'}\right)^{\frac{b}{1-b}}.
\end{align*}
We now fix $c'$ by setting $c = c' \cdot \left(\frac{c}{c-c'}\right)^{\frac{b}{1-b}}$. We obtain with some
algebraic manipulation an equation relating $c$ and $c'$,
$$
(c-c')^b c^{1-b} = (c')^{1-b} \cdot c^{b}.
$$
Although not obvious at first sight, this equation defines a line in the $(c, c')$-plane. Let $
c' = \alpha_b c$; then the above yields in turn an equation for $\alpha_b$:
$$
c^b \cdot (1 - \alpha_b)^b c^{1-b} = \alpha_b^{1-b} \cdot c^{1-b} c^b \iff \alpha_b + \alpha_b^{\frac{1-b}{b}}
= 1.
$$
Let $g(x) = x + x^{\frac{1-b}{b}}$. Since $g$ is continuous and monotone increasing, and $g(0) = 0$
and $g(1) = 2$, there exists by the intermediate value theorem a unique $\alpha_b \in (0, 1)$ such
that $g(\alpha_b) = 1$.
Thus, the above equation has a solution in $(0, 1)$ for every fixed $b \in (0, 1)$.
Let $z_n = f(n)$ for $n \geq 1$. All together, the above yields that $z_n$ satisfies the recurrence
inequality
$$
z_{n+1} \leq z_{n} + c \cdot (z_{n})^b
$$
with $z_1 = y_1$. Consequently, for all $n \geq 1$ we have $z_n \leq y_n$, thus finding that
$$
a_{n} \geq y_{n-n_0} \geq z_{n-n_0} = ((1-b)c)^{\frac{1}{1-b}} \cdot \left[1 + \alpha_b \cdot (n-n_0)\right]^{\frac{1}{1-b}} \sim C_{b,n_0} \cdot n^{\frac{1}{1-b}}.
$$
